# Media query is not working in Huawei mobile

Tags: android, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a new site that works in other mobile devices, I'm using media query for responsive, I tried to clear cache, but still not working.

It's still look broken in Huawei, meanwhile other device looks great, I'm wondering if there's setup in query that I'm not aware of? Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Are other devices including a tablet? could it be that your dimensions for the Huawei screen are not correctly defined? Are you following a device agnostic approach?

Comment: @Lelo Only for Huawei, on the other device is responsive, I'm not sure the dimension of Huawei, but phone is larger, but it working